# Update Table from Another table with condition and ID with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 005_my_sc table with column

```
pdb_id  listing_type
1       new
2       sale
3       rent
```

and I also have 005_my_cl table with column

```
pdb_id  listing_type
1       0
2       0
3       0
```

I want to update 005_my_cl table with following condition

- 005_my_sc ID match 005_my_cl ID
- if listing_type in 005_my_sc = 'new' => listing_type in 005_my_cl = 2
- if listing_type in 005_my_sc = 'rent' => listing_type in 005_my_cl = 1
- if listing_type in 005_my_sc = 'sale' => listing_type in 005_my_cl = 2

Here's what I am trying:

```
update 005_my_sc old, 005_my_cl new1 
set new1.listing_type = 2 
where old.pdb_id = new1.pdb_id and old.listing_type = 'new'
```

The code has no syntax error but nothing change, what did i miss ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, mate:

```
UPDATE 005_my_sc t1
    INNER JOIN 005_my_cl t2 ON t2.pdb_id = t1.pdb_id
SET t2.listing_type = (
    CASE t1.listing_type
        WHEN 'new' THEN 2
        WHEN 'rent' THEN 1
        WHEN 'sale' THEN 2
    END
)
WHERE t1.listing_type IN ('new', 'rent', 'sale');
```

Maybe you missed these items

- You can use any type of `JOIN` when updating
- The default value for the listing type that is not ('new', 'rent', 'sale') so you won't need this line anymore `WHERE t1.listing_type IN ('new', 'rent', 'sale')`

Considering you have a default value, you can use this instead:

```
UPDATE 005_my_sc t1
    INNER JOIN 005_my_cl t2 ON t2.pdb_id = t1.pdb_id
SET t2.listing_type = (
    CASE t1.listing_type
        WHEN 'new' THEN 2
        WHEN 'rent' THEN 1
        WHEN 'sale' THEN 2
        ELSE 2
    END
);
```